# What's the reasoning behind the 'name' property of a named JavaScript function expression returning the assigned function's variable name?

Tags: javascript, function

I'm curious why a named function expression's `name` property is the value of the function declaration construct's name, rather than the variable that can be used to execute the function.

```js
function functionDeclaration(){
   return;
}

var anonymousFunctionExpression = function(){
   return;
}

var namedFunctionExpression = function functionName(){
  return;
}


console.log(functionDeclaration.name);//As expected, function name is 'functionDeclaration'
console.log(anonymousFunctionExpression.name);//As expected, function name is 'anonymousFunctionExpression'
console.log(namedFunctionExpression.name);//Why is the function's name 'functionName' and not 'namedFunctionExpression?'
```

Comment: because you explicitly named the function? In case 1 and case 3, you declared a function _with a name_ so that's what `.name` is going to point to. Case 2 is the surprising one, but [does some name-finding magic as of ES6](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name#Inferred_function_names).

Comment: I mean... one *has* to take precedence over the other. Why should the variable name take precedence over the actual name of the function?

Comment: Note in particular [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36498151/902497) that cites the spec: An assignment operation updates the `name` property only if the function doesn't already have a `name`.

Comment: So it seems that the answer is "because that's what the spec says", I'm was wondering the thought process behind defining what gets precedence.

Comment: Well it kinda makes sense that an explicit name takes precedence over an infered one. The `name` property is just there to be helpful in debugging which is the only reason the inference is there at all.

Answer (score -2):

That's just how it works. *If* the function in the function expression is named, that name (on the right of the `=`) will be used - otherwise, if not named, the `.name` will give you the variable name the function was assigned to *when the function was created*. (If it's a function declaration and not a function expression, then the `.name` is just the name of the declared function.)

Note that if you reassign a function created anonymously, its `name` remains the original variable name the function was assigned to. This is what's happening in case 2, when the interpreter must infer the variable name:

```js
const fn = () => {};
const fn2 = fn;
console.log(fn.name);
console.log(fn2.name);
```

In cases 1 and 3, the interpreter does not need to infer the variable name, because the function has an explicit name already when it was defined:

```
function functionDeclaration(){
    //   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   return;
}
// and
var namedFunctionExpression = function functionName(){
    return;                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^
}
```

The interpreter would only keep track of the `namedFunctionExpression` if it needs to [*infer*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name#Inferred_function_names) the function name from its creation context (which is an ES2015 feature) - and this inference is only done in case 2.